# Issue with adding sudzc.xcode framework to my application

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I am using web service in my IOS application. Its all the WSDL calls. So i used Sudzc.com to generate all the service call Soap requests. Here my problem is how to add the generated sudzc.xcode framework to my application. Someone told me like we can add generated .xcode framework to our application. Can any one please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, please follow the movy that is on the sudzc page. It helped me too.

Here a link to the movy:
http://sudzc.com/Tutorial/ObjC.mov

For automatic reference counting, select it from the dropdown.